# How to parse JSON when one of my parameters is incorporated into the JSON itself?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, networking, struct

I'm new to JSON parsing. I'm trying to retrieve weather data using an API. Users input a city name as a textfield string, which will then be passed into a networking method that should retrieve the temperature for this city.
The JSON looks like this:

```
"remainingCost": 0,
  "queryCost": 1,
  "messages": null,
  "locations": {
    "London": {
      "stationContributions": null,
      "values": [
        {
          "wdir": 322.4,
          "uvindex": 3.0,
          "datetimeStr": "2022-09-28T17:00:00+01:00",
          "preciptype": "",
          "cin": -2.0,
          "cloudcover": 57.4,
          "pop": 19.0,
          "datetime": 1664384400000,
          "precip": 0.0,
          "solarradiation": 280.0,
          "dew": 4.0,
          "humidity": 49.9,
          "temp": 14.3,
          "visibility": 15.0,
          "wspd": 6.0,
          "severerisk": 10.0,
          "solarenergy": 1.0,
          "heatindex": null,
          "snowdepth": 0.0,
          "sealevelpressure": 1000.0,
          "snow": 0.0,
          "wgust": 15.4,
          "conditions": "Partially cloudy",
          "windchill": null,
          "cape": 11.0
        }
```

Now, I've learned that I can build structs to host the decoded JSON data once I retrieve it, and I've created the following:

```
struct WeatherModel: Decodable {
    
    let locations: Locations
}

struct Locations: Decodable {
    
    let London: London
}

struct London: Decodable {
    
    let values: [Values]
}

struct Values: Decodable {
    
    let temp: Double
}
```

Then, using my decoder, I am able to successfully retrieve "temp". So far so good.

The issue is that "temp" is contained inside "values" which is contained inside "London", which is then contained inside "locations". However 'London' should not be called each time, only if the user enters 'London' in the textfield. If they entered 'Paris', for example, then my structs would no longer work, and as far as I know I can't make a 'variable' struct that would accept any city name as its name.

How can I resolve this so that I can get the different city weather depending on the input? Is there a different way of housing the JSON? Is this a shortcoming of the API itself, and maybe I should find a different data source? Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: what API are you trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

For this one, I suggest you create the object model like this:

```
struct WeatherModel: Decodable {
    let locations: [String: Any?]
}

struct City: Decodable {
    let values: [Values]
}

struct Values: Decodable {
    let temp: Double
}
```

And when you get the `WeatherModel` it will include `locations` as the `[String: Any?]`. Now, get the dictionary of the city by using the key is city name.

```
let cityDictionary = weatherModel.locations["cityName"] as? [String: Any?]
```

The last thing is using `JSONSerialization` to decode the dictionary into the object, or get the object value key by key.